# Efficient way of merging classes

Tags: c#, reflection

I have this class:

```
public class CompetitionBindingViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class CompetitionViewModel : CompetitionBindingViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Logo { get; set; }
    public string BackgroundImage { get; set; }
    public string ColourScheme { get; set; }
    public bool Current { get; set; }

    public CompetitionViewModel(Competition model)
    {
        this.Id = model.Id;
        this.Name = model.Name;
        this.Description = model.Description;
        this.Logo = model.Logo;
        this.BackgroundImage = model.BackgroundImage;
        this.ColourScheme = model.ColourScheme;
        this.Current = model.Current;
    }
}
```

As you can see there are 2 **ViewModels** here. One is for when a **competition** is first created (only the **Name** and **Description** need to be supplied. Later in the project I want to assign a **Logo**, **BackgroundImage** and **ColourScheme**, but these are not required.
I also have a **Current** value which by default is set to **False**.
I have this function which handles all that:

```
[Route("")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Put(CompetitionViewModel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return BadRequest(ModelState);

    try
    {
        var competition = await this.service.GetAsync(model.Id);

        competition.Name = (string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.Name)) ? competition.Name : model.Name;
        competition.Description = (string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.Description)) ? competition.Description : model.Description;
        competition.Logo = (string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.Logo)) ? competition.Logo : model.Logo;
        competition.BackgroundImage = (string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.BackgroundImage)) ? competition.BackgroundImage : model.BackgroundImage;
        competition.ColourScheme = (string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.ColourScheme)) ? competition.ColourScheme : model.ColourScheme;
        competition.Current = (model.Current == competition.Current) ? competition.Current : model.Current;

        this.service.Update(competition);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return InternalServerError(ex);
    }

    return await base.SaveChanges();
}
```

Now, I like neat code and this just not do it for me. The lines that are an issue are these ones here:

```
competition.Name = (string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.Name)) ? competition.Name : model.Name;
competition.Description = (string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.Description)) ? competition.Description : model.Description;
competition.Logo = (string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.Logo)) ? competition.Logo : model.Logo;
competition.BackgroundImage = (string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.BackgroundImage)) ? competition.BackgroundImage : model.BackgroundImage;
competition.ColourScheme = (string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.ColourScheme)) ? competition.ColourScheme : model.ColourScheme;
competition.Current = (model.Current == competition.Current) ? competition.Current : model.Current;
```

What I am trying to do is check to see if a **Property** has changed. If it has, then take the new value otherwise leave it alone.

Can someone help me provide a better solution because this happens a lot (I have other classes and functions that do the same thing but with different properties).

I would prefer **not** to use a library as I don't like have libraries and using a tiny bit of it when it is there to address a multitude of situations.

Comment: "I would prefer not to use a library as I don't like have libraries " Please stop using the .net framework, as it is a giant library designed to address a multitude of situation. Please stop using Windows since it is an OS designed to address a multitude of situations. Please stop using the Intel x86 family General Purpose Central Processing Unit because it is designed to address a multitude of situations.

Comment: Please also read up the HTTP specification as you a completely abusing the `PUT` keyword where you are looking for `PATCH`. Along with `Delta<Competition>` class from the Web API library. Sorry you didn't want to use a library...

Comment: Thanks for this reply. It was really useful.
I am fully aware of mandatory libraries. What I don't want is a myriad of libraries to handle small tasks because it becomes huge when it could (hopefully) be fixed with a single class or function.

Comment: As for abusing PUT, here take a look at this: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/creating-web-apis/creating-a-web-api-that-supports-crud-operations

Comment: You DO realise that you are already using ASP.net Web API which is by no means a mandatory library.

Comment: Also there is AutoMapper. Which is a library, which isn't for a multitude of situations. It is designed for this ONE situation. If that isn't good enough... Just copy the source...

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just create a helper method or something? Not that it's pretty or has any error checking, but this works:

```
public static void UpdateValueIfChanged<TData,TValue>(TData data, Expression<Func<TData,TValue>> propFunc, TValue newValue)
{
    var prop = (MemberExpression)propFunc.Body;
    var propInfo = (PropertyInfo)prop.Member;

    Func<TData, TValue> getFunc = propFunc.Compile();
    TValue originalValue = getFunc(data);
    if (!EqualityComparer<TValue>.Default.Equals(originalValue,newValue))
    {
        propInfo.SetMethod.Invoke(data, new object[] { newValue });
    }
}
```

You can call it like `UpdateIfChanged(competition c => c.Name, model.Name)`.